# How to increase the width of the progress Bar dynamically

Tags: javascript

I am currently working on a dynamic progress bar that should fill up everytime I click on the button(Meaning increasing the width of the element inside the bar container), The way I am doing it is like that:

```
let btn = document.getElementById('click');
let adj = add_bar.style.width = "";

btn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{

 adj = "10%";
})
```

And I have done some other attempts, but they all ended up with the same result.
can you give me hints at least?

thank you

Comment: Are you using a `progress` element?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/progress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your code is not working is because you are setting the width to `10%` every time you click it, rather than incrementing.

Instead, use `+=`:

```js
let add_bar = document.querySelector('progress');
let btn = document.getElementById('click');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  add_bar.value += 10;
})
```

```html
<progress value="0" min="0" max="100"></progress>
<br/>
<button id="click">Increase Progress</button>
```

Comment: Ok, thank you, But what i needed is to increase the width everytime by 10% for example, I've Run the code snippet of the code you just pasted here and I see that it fills the whole bar by just one click

Comment: Cool, that's what i am really looking for, thank you